# Using a development language (Python) before putting it into C++

Tags: c++, python

I'm kinda having a debate here with my friend, whether it's OK to have a development language before putting the idea into C++.

When I say development language I mean a language to try ideas out before putting them into the compiled language, in this case C++.

My friend thinks it's unnecessary (and maybe a waste of time) to do this because we basically have to re-write code, or in other words, port the code from the dev language to C++ code.

I think otherwise though, it saves a lot more time to be porting the code than to wait for the C++ code to be compiled over and over while we test little things out.

FYI, we're talking about code for a small application, the idea is for the entire application (actually a game), once done weighs less than 100MB, however I'm aware the size already compiled is much MUCH smaller than in code.

Of course, this can also go the other way around, should we only use the compiled language (C++) or should we only use the scripting language (Python).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We do this all the time; code applications in Python, evolve it rapidly (easy with Python), then replace *critical parts* with Python C extensions when necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perfectly ok, its called [prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototyping), also [software prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping). Wether or not it suits your particular application is something you need to decide on your own. For example, testing a GUI design migth be something worth mocking up quickly, just to see and feel how it'd work.